# .pluck returning undefined in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Trying to pull a list of ratings from a collection of Reviews and then average them to come up with an aggregated average rating for a Plate. When I look at the data output from the ratings variable I get nothing but "undefined undefined undefined".

```
averageRating: function() {
    var reviews = Reviews.findOne({plateId: this._id});
    var ratings = _.pluck(reviews, 'rating');
    var sum = ratings.reduce(function(pv, cv){return pv + cv;}, 0);
    var avg = sum / ratings.length;

    //Testing output
    var test = "";
    var x;
    for (x in reviews) {
        text += reviews[x] + ',';
    }

    return test;
}
```

Sorry if this is a super newbie question, but I've been at this for hours and cannot figure it out.

Comment: do `console.log` after each computation to see whether data is being computed or not.

Comment: It's not the computation part that's the issue. Before I ever do any of the math I'm getting "undefined". In the above code I'm temporarily bypassing the math part and just outputting what I've received from .pluck which is "undefined undefined undefined (etc)" .

Comment: Your query returns a single document, at most. What does the document look like? What are you getting before calling `pluck()`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. As listed above `var reviews` gets set to a cursor which apparently .pluck does not work on. By first converting the cursor to an array of objects I was then able to use .pluck. So updated code looks like this:

```
averageRating: function() {
    var reviewsCursor = Reviews.find({plateId: this._id});
    //Converts cursor to an array of objects
    var reviews = reviewsCursor.fetch();
    var ratings = _.pluck(reviews, 'rating');
    var sum = ratings.reduce(function(pv, cv){return pv + cv;}, 0);
    var avg = (sum / ratings.length).toPrecision(2);

    return avg;

}
```